# Error with JSON in Android Studio

Tags: android, mysql, json

This code gets the data of usernames from my MySQL Server. Whenever I run it, I get an error on this `JSONArray js=new JSONArray(result);`. The console gives no other details. Please help.

```
private String getdata(){
            try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
                HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
                //Log.d("TheRealapp", result);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                JSONArray js=new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject jo = null;

                data = new String[js.length()];
                for(int i=0;i<js.length();i++){
                    jo=js.getJSONObject(i);
                    data[i]= jo.getString("username");
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return String.valueOf(getdata());
            //Log.d("TheRealapp", String.valueOf(data));

        }
```

Here is my server side code:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("html_errors", false); 
require "conn.php";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM UserData");

if ($query){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $flag[] =$row;


    }
    print(json_encode($flag));


}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: `The console gives no other details` I don't believe it.

Comment: Hey guys, I need more help.Should this code work? The one I have now?

Answer (score 0):

your string "result" , is not a valid json encoded string. so the constructor cannot make a jsonArray out of it;
see the link below:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
it helps you on server side code , and teaches you how to encode a string to json using php.

Comment: so how do I fix it

Comment: it's not about your android code , it's about the web service which is not responding to your request correctly. make sure that the response is json encoded.

Comment: I just edited the response, I hope it helps you, if it does up-vote.

Comment: I changed my response to implement what i have for server side code. Please help.